# What can I do to reduce anger, greed, lust, fear and ego?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, upanishads

As per Hindu scriptures,
What are the things one can do in daily life that would reduce anger, greed, lust, fear and ego over time?

Please don't say "surrender yourself to the lord" that's not what I am looking for. Also "do your karma" & "follow your dharma" does not count because they are way too high level for a poor soul like me.

Comment: The farther you walk east, the farther away from the west you become. The farther you walk towards God, the farther away will be bad habits. You need not give them up, they will drop off by themselves. Think of the Lord, chant his name, practice meditation. A tree grows from a tiny seed almost imperceptibly, change occurs slowly, it does not happen overnight. The Astavakra Samhita 1.11 says: "A man who says he is free becomes free, a man who says he is bound remains bound. This popular saying is true - 'As you think so you become.'"

Comment: Sir, I agree with every word you say. But a 'sansari' needs to have some practical things that will help him slowly enrich his 'jivatma'. Moksha should not be only for 'sanyasis'. And so my question is from a layman's perspective.

Comment: @sv. - That's a good catch. Looks very much similar.

Comment: A simple and very effective way to control six enemies of man is, don't expect anything from any one. This simple thing if you practice every day and see the results for yourself. All those six problems start with expecting something from others. That's why God tells us do your work but don't expect the result. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: thinking and chanting are practical. When you are working, how many times does your mind drift off to daydreams and other impractical things? In any given minute during the day, many many times. Instead, chant inside your mind, chant softly with your tongue. Control your mind. It is a muscle like any other muscle and can be taught to do what you want.

Comment: And from your comment you believe you are bound- and bound you will remain. As you think so you become. Again, Astavakra Samhita. It is not empty words. Practical? Swami VIvekananda says: "Realize yourself. That is all there is to do. Know yourself as you really are--infinite spirit. That is practical religion. Everything else is impractical, for everything else will vanish. That alone will never vanish. It is eternal. Hospitals will tumble down, Railroad givers will all die. This earth will be blown to pieces, suns wiped out. The soul endureth for ever."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is about  overcoming or wining **Shadripus (षड्रिपु) meaning the six enemies of Human beings** , as told in Hinduism. They are as follows.

1. Lust (Sanskrit: Kama) (काम)
2. Greed (Sanskrit: Lobha)(लोभ)
3. Anger (Sanskrit: Krodha)(क्रोध)
4. Pride (Sanskrit: Mada)(मद)
5. Attachment (Sanskrit: Moha)(मोहा)
6. Covetousness (Sanskrit: Matsarya)(मत्सर)

These [six enemies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadripu) of man can become an obstacle in his spiritual progress and material progress. These qualities cannot be helpful in achieving material benefits, not to speak of spiritual progress. So, one should try to give up such qualities. In my view , for this one can practice :

- Yoga,
- Meditation ,
- Pranayama (Breathing excercise)
- and the recitation ofvarious shanti mantras (With advice of spiritual teacher or Guru )

  also one can practice  reading sacred texts and attending discourse
  of saints, Gurus etc.

There is a simple advice given in **Epic Mahabharata's section of Udyoga Parva**   about conquering these six enemies.

> **अक्रोधेन जयेत् क्रोधमसाधुं साधुना जयेत् ।**     **जयेत् कदर्यं दानेन जयेत्**
>   **सत्येन चानृतम्**
>
> a-krodhéna jayét krodham_asādhum sādhunā jayét | jayét kadaryam 
>   dānéna, jayét satyéna chānṛitam || [IAST]
>
> **Conquer anger by calmness; evil by good; miserliness by charity and
>   lies by truth.**
>
> [Mahabharata Udyog Parva](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-mbh-05:section-39)

Additional Ref. For Shloka : http://sanskritpearls.blogspot.in/2010/06/june-26th.html

Comment: Even the good virtues give rise to the evil inside. Being good, truthful and philanthropic gives birth to 'ego'. How to fight that ?

Comment: @WeShall - There is famous Verse in Shree Gita by Lord Krishna.  " कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन। 
मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि॥ २-४७
Meaning - You have the right to work only , but never to its fruits.
Let not the fruits of action be your motive, nor let your attachment be to inaction. 
 So according to it , do your KARMA  as Directed by scriptures. And just "Believe" , Leave The Rest On To HIM...       All The Best ...